# Overlapping Layout in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have an overlapping layout which is caused by this XML file which I explained below the cause of this problem:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_top_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_frame_top_navigation" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_tab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_frame_button" >
</FrameLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/translucent_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_frame_tab" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_frame_tab" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_title_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_frame_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_time_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_frame_title_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_frame_time_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_frame_login"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
</FrameLayout>
```

The layout presented is the list of all containers. Now after having the containers placed on it, I noticed that there is a bug since I've got an overlapping out.

Here's the UI of my application:

[image]

The main container of the application is added into `main_frame_tab` with `match_parent` height since it's height depends on the present containers below. It can't be changed to `wrap_content` because I won't achieve what I want and won't solve this problem.

The main reason of this overlapping bug is that some contents of menu are actually placed under the menu at the bottom of the page.

To explain it further, you can also notice that the setup of containers is using `layout_below` until middle and on the containers at the bottom I used `layout_above` and there's a space in between that aren't connected which could have caused the overlapping.

What ways to solve this overlapping structure?

Comment: Is this actually a screenshot of an Android app?

Comment: Nope. But achieved it in Android, almost the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame_top_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_frame_top_navigation" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame_tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_frame_button" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/translucent_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_frame_tab" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/translucent_container"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_frame_tab" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame_title_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_frame_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame_time_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_frame_title_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_frame_time_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_frame_login" >
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't work. The main_frame_bottom_navigation should be at the bottom all the time but if there is no main_frame_content the menu will go up and if there's a content, the menu won't appear on the screen.